# Why is my Google automl vision trained on cloud much better than the one trained on edge

Tags: google-vision, google-cloud-automl, automl

I am new to Google Vision and i just tried a dataset to train. I first trained it on edge and another time on cloud hosted. In both cases I used the suggested nodes per hours. My model on edge is much worse than on cloud. Can someone explain this? don't they both train in the cloud and should've the same results? I thought the difference is only, that on edge it is possible to export the model.
I used a image classification
Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both are indeed trained on cloud, but difference is where each model is intended to use.

Edge models are lighter, in terms of model size and computation needed to perform prediction, that is why they are not as good as cloud models. Intention of edge models is to **run on edge devices(like mobile devices)** which do no have much computational power like that of GPU cloud instances.(Probably this is the reason why Google allows you to export edge models so that they can be used offline on mobile devices.)

On the other hand, models trained for cloud usage gives more preference to model accuracy, which are intended to be run on big GPU/CPU machines.
There is a trade-of between edge models and cloud models. Edge models are have low memory requirements where accuracy is compromised and higher latency, whereas cloud models are more accurate with comparatively higher memory requirements.